# Radzen DataGrid - use data annotation for column heading

Tags: c#, datagrid, blazor, syncfusion, radzen

I am using data annotation in my models:

```
[Display(Name ="First Name")]
public string? First_Name
```

If I use Syncfusion DataGrid, that picks up the annotation and uses it for my column headings.  However, if I try to use the Radzen DataGrid, if I don't specify Title, I get no column headings.  Is it possible to use data annotation with Radzen DataGrid?

Comment: Reading the docs i think today doesnt exist that functionality in radzen, in this cases i use a resource file where i store display name, and then reuse it in column name